# Iterate over strings in command

Tags: python, loops, operators, functools

I have code that looks like this:

```
n = 2
disc_weights = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, 4*n)

phi =     (disc_weights[0] * QubitOperator('X0') + 
           disc_weights[1] * QubitOperator('Y0') +
           disc_weights[2] * QubitOperator('Z0') +
           disc_weights[3] * QubitOperator('X1') +
           disc_weights[4] * QubitOperator('Y1') +
           disc_weights[5] * QubitOperator('Z1') + 
           disc_weights[6] * QubitOperator('')   + 
           disc_weights[7] * QubitOperator('')   )
```

where QubitOperator is a command in a package I am using. How can I automate this to iterate over X, Y, Z, , 1, 2...n and create phi?

This somewhat does the trick but not quite there yet

```
phi=  functools.reduce(operator.add, (1 * QubitOperator(f'{a}{n}') for  a,n in itertools.product(["X", "Y", "Z"], range(n))))
```

Comment: `itertools.product('XYZ',range(n))`

Comment: You can use `sum()` instead of `functools.reduce`

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 2

disc_weights = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, 4*n)

iter_ = itertools.product('XYZ', range(n))

tuple_wrapper = lambda t: f'{t[0]}{t[1]}'

sum_ = 0.0 * QubitOperator('')
for dw in disc_weights:
    try:
        sum_ += dw * QubitOperator(tuple_wrapper(next(iter_))) 
    except StopIteration:
        sum_ += dw * QubitOperator('')
```

Comment: ''' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-40e9dc866e6d> in <module>
     10 for dw in disc_weights:
     11     try:
---> 12         sum_ += dw * QubitOperator(tuple_wrapper(next(iter_)))
     13     except StopIteration:
     14         sum_ += dw * QubitOperator('')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'QubitOperator' '''

Comment: This has to do with how `QubitOperator` multiples and adds with other types. I don't know what the return value for `float * QubitOperatr()` is, so you'll have to figure that part out. But other than that this recipe should work.

Comment: ```type(2 * QubitOperator('X0'))``` is openfermion.ops._qubit_operator.QubitOperator.

Output from ```2 * QubitOperator('X0')``` is 2.0 [X0]

Comment: Right, so you just can't initialize `sum_ = 0`, you have to put in a dummy `openfermion.ops._qubit_operator.QubitOperator` value so that you can do the sum. What is `openfermion.ops._qubit_operator.QubitOperator`'s version of 0, use that.